# How does a h.265 bitstream relate to its trace file?

Tags: trace, hex-editors, h.265

I am using the https://hevc.hhi.fraunhofer.de/svn/svn_HEVCSoftware/tags/HM-16.9 version of the H265 video encoder, and used it to generate a TraceDec.txt file which contains VPS, PPS, PPS, and slice header symbols (e.g `vps_video_parameter_set_id u(4): 0`)

I was told to match the bits of the .265 file with the symbols of the TraceDec.txt file using a hex editor. I opened the .265 file with a hex editor, but I have no clue how these bits correspond to the symbols in the trace file. The manual doesn't seem to help, either. Do the first bits of the file even start with the VPS?